# storing a string from google webapp into an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Suppose I would like to create an array on my JS code and push in a string coming from appscript htmlservice. How do I do it? The below does not work.

```
     var array = [];
     <? var data = getData(); ?>
          <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>      
             <?= array.push(data[i]) ?>                   
         <? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

```
var array = [];
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  array.push(<?= data[i] ?>); // Modified
<? } ?>

console.log(array);
```

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: @carlesgg97 Thank you for editing it. I could study from your edit.