# Google Webapp: How to dynamically pass array values to jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I've been working on an answer to StackOverflow question [Datepicker: Disabling dates in the data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58794323/1330560). I've successfully developed a small webapp that excludes specific dates from a jQuery Datepicker using the `beforeShowDay` option and an array of hardcoded dates.

### Problem

At present, the array of excluded dates is hard coded, but these dates should be generated dynamically. Although I have a function in code.gs `getuserdates()` which will return the "userdates" array `["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"]`, I haven't found a single reference on the web to explain how to pass the array values dynamically to the webapp.

The answer by @Tanaike on [Disable dates in the datepicker based on values from the Google Sheet using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57140560/1330560) seems relevant to this problem, but I've failed to adapt any successful code that includes the array. I think part of the problem here is that Tanaike's answer was 100% Javascript whereas this scenario requires both Javascript and jQuery.

I tried scriptlets (not expecting them to work, but you never know. They all generated an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

- `var userdates = <? getuserdates(); ?>`
- `var userdates = <?= getuserdates(); ?>`
- `var userdates = <?!= getuserdates(); ?>`

**Goal**
To update dynamically the values of the variable `array`.

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1shHxpM1maOuXdajI8Kwo-QzLtseeryt0c5QyHnfhv48/edit?usp=sharing)

[Latest webapp url (updated)](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwOw9THlNShp9o1yrFw3FbtIfCcLMIuPsKN4khSuARp3lilNswQ/exec)

**Code**

The following code works flawlessly; the only problem is that the array values are hard coded.

*code.gs*

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function getuserdates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetname = "VL Request";
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
 
  // assume user name
  //var userName = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername()
  var username = "user1";
  
  // set variables
  var datafirstrow = 2;
  var dataLR = datasheet.getLastRow();
  var dataLC = datasheet.getLastColumn();
  var datasheetRange = datasheet.getRange(datafirstrow,1, dataLR-datafirstrow+1, dataLC);
  //Logger.log(datasheetRange.getA1Notation());
  
  // sort the data by date
  datasheetRange.sort(6); // sort by Column F - VL date
  var datasheetData = datasheetRange.getDisplayValues();
  //Logger.log(datasheetData);
  
  //   get the user names as an array
  var datanames = datasheetData.map(function(e){return e[2];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
  //Logger.log(datanames); // DEBUG
  //Logger.log(datanames.length) // DEBUG
  
  // create an array to hold any dates
  var userdates = [];

  //  loop through the user names; test for equivalence to "username", and save VF date to an array
  for (var i=0;i<datanames.length;i++){
    //Logger.log("dataname = "+datanames[i])
    if (datanames[i] === username){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i= "+i+", user name = "+datanames[i]+", VL date = "+datasheetData[i][5]);
      userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i= "+i+" - no match");
    }
  }
  // resort the data by Timestamp
   datasheetRange.sort(1); // sort by Column A
  
  if (userdates.length !=0){
  //Logger.log("There are "+userdates.length+" previous dates for this user.");//DEBUG
  }
  else{
  //Logger.log("There no previous dates for this user");//DEBUG
  }
  
  //Logger.log(userdates);
  return userdates;
}
```

---

*Page.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="demo" >
    <h1>jQuery datepicker</h1>
     <p>click here : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </div>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

*JavaScript.html*

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var userdates = ["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"];

$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "+3W", 
    maxDate: "+12W",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      $thisDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've added a link to the spreadsheet, which will give access to the project. I've also updated the link to the webapp (it now links to the shared copy of the spreadsheet).

Comment: I've added the script (in code.gs) for `getuserdates()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `getuserdates()` in Google Apps Script side returns the value of `["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"]`, `userdates` of `var userdates = <?= getuserdates(); ?>` is `12/13/2019,12/14/2019,12/16/2019,12/17/2019,12/24/2019` of the string type. I thought that by this, your script doesn't work.

So, as one of several answers, how about this answer? Please modify `JavaScript.html`.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the scriptlets are used. I thought that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58810165) might be useful.

#### From:

```
var userdates = ["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"];
```

#### To:

```
var userdates = [];
<? var data = getuserdates(); ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  userdates.push(<?= data[i] ?>);
<? } ?>
```

- When the script is run, `userdates` is `["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"]`.
- As one more pattern using the scriptlets, for example, if you want to use `var userdates = <?= getuserdates(); ?>`, you can also modify `var userdates = <?= getuserdates(); ?>` to `var userdates = <?= getuserdates() ?>.split(",");`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, google.script.run is used.

#### From:

```
var userdates = ["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"];
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(userdates => {
  $(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
      minDate: "+3W", 
      maxDate: "+12W",
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        $thisDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {
          return [true, ""];
        } else {
          return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
      }
    });
  });
}).getuserdates();
```

- When the script is run, `userdates` retrieved from `getuserdates()` is used as `["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"]`.

### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that `getuserdates()` returns `["12/13/2019", "12/14/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/24/2019"]`.

### References:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)
- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Edit 1:

#### About issue 1:

About the reason that the error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` occurs, the reason of this issue is `<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>`. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
</div>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</body>
```

#### To:

```
</div>
<script>
var userdates = [];
<? var data = getuserdates(); ?>
<? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
  userdates.push(<?= data[i] ?>);
<? } ?>
</script>
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</body>
```

- In this case, please don't add `<script>###</script>` to `JavaScript` of `<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>`.
- Unfortunately, it seems that the scriptlets cannot be used into the scriptlets.

#### About issue 2:

About the reason that `[""12/11/2019"", ""12/15/2019"", ""12/16/2019"", ""12/17/2019"", ""12/24/2019""]` is returned from `getuserdates()`, the reason of this issue is `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');`. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');
```

#### To:

```
userdates.push(datasheetData[i][5]);
```

### Edit 2:

When the pattern 1 is used, the script is as follows. About `getuserdates()` of GAS side, please modify from `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');` to `userdates.push(datasheetData[i][5]);`. And please modify HTML & Javascript side as follows.

#### HTML & Javascript: Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="demo" >
    <h1>jQuery datepicker</h1>
     <p>click here : <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </div>
    <script>
    var userdates = [];
    <? var data = getuserdates(); ?>
    <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      userdates.push(<?= data[i] ?>);
    <? } ?>
    </script>
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### HTML & Javascript: JavaScript.html

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "+3W", 
    maxDate: "+12W",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      $thisDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Good news and bad news. Pattern1: returns `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and the DataPicker does not open; Pattern 2: The Datepicker opens, though there are no excluded dates (getting closer?). What do you make, if anything, of the script being jQuery but the scriptlet being Javascript?

Comment: Re: Pattern 2, I ran console.log and it is returning ` [""12/11/2019"", ""12/15/2019"", ""12/16/2019"", ""12/17/2019"", ""12/24/2019""]` - note the double sets of quotes. I have almost no experience with console.log - does it this look right?  Logger.log has the "conventional, single set of quotes around each value, as described in the question.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your updated question, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Update: Your Pattern#2 answer is successful. There was a mistake in my `getuserdates()` function. I had already used `getDisplayValues()` to render the array values as strings; then, in my infinite wisdom, I did `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');` instead of `userdates.push(datasheetData[i][5]);`. The reason for this, as I recall, was to put "quote" marks around the values (sigh). Once I pushed the non-quoted values, the Datepicker opens with the `userdates` values shown as unavailable. Pattern#1 values were still unsuccessful.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved by the pattern 2. But about the pattern 1, in my environment, I can confirm that the script works. So can you update your shared Spreadsheet by updating the script? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');` You saw and recognised it faster than me.

Comment: @Tedinoz I added the modified script for the pattern 1. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I made the changes that you suggested, and Pattern1 is also successful.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from the Apps Script runtime with client-side code.

To do this you need to handle the response from the function you calling with the [`withSuccessHandler` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction).

Changing your function to create the DatePicker with the date returned from the backend would look like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
function onSuccess(value) {
  var userdates = value;
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: "+3W", 
    maxDate: "+12W",
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      $thisDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
      if ($.inArray($thisDate, userdates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
      } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
      }
    }
  });
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getuserdates();
</script>
```

Comment: The Datepicker opens, but there are no excluded dates. Array value = `[""12/11/2019"", ""12/15/2019"", ""12/16/2019"", ""12/17/2019"", ""12/24/2019""]` (also noted in my comment on Tanaike's answer). Perhaps this is suggesting an error in my `getuserdates()` script

Comment: @Tedinoz are these values `Date` values or just Strings?

Could you get their `typeof` ?

Comment: Update: Your answer is successful. There was a mistake in my `getuserdates()` function. I had already used `getDisplayValues()` to render the array values as strings; then, in my infinite wisdom, I did `userdates.push('"' + datasheetData[i][5]+ '"');` instead of `userdates.push(datasheetData[i][5]);`. The reason for this, as I recall, was to put "quote" marks around the values (sigh). Once I pushed the non-quoted values, the Datepicker opens with the `userdates` values shown as unavailable.

Comment: @Tedinoz glad to be of help. Remember to accept answers that are useful so others can find it as well!